# Trying to create a several boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to make a plot with six boxplots in it,

Im not sure exactly how to start with this but using `ggplot`

Im hoping to get a series of 6 boxplots in a row:

1. 3 boxplots for the three variables under `A5` (1,0, and NA)
2. 3 boxplots for the variables under `A9` (1, 0, and NA).
3. Then populate the boxplot with the respective value from `maf`. I've been trying to plot them but I get either just the maf column plotted or a grey slab. Any help would be amazing thank you.

```
   A5 A9         maf
1   1 NA 9.33843e-01
2   1  1 2.07735e-01
3   1  1 9.28438e-01
4   1  1 7.17963e-01
5   0 NA 1.02935e-01
6   1  1 9.28281e-01
7   1  1 9.28100e-01
8   1  1 2.85170e-01
9   1  1 2.67085e-01
10  1  1 9.28339e-01
11  1  1 5.68334e-02
12  1  1 4.87848e-01
13  1  1 2.22414e-01
14  1  1 3.37689e-01
15  1  1 1.09452e-01
16  1  1 4.71361e-02
17 NA NA 6.87674e-01
18  0  0 5.03323e-01
19  1  1 8.93953e-01
20  1  1 9.13662e-01
```

EDIT----------------------------------------------------------
When running the code on the original data with e-9 exponents:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -maf
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, maf, fill=factor(value))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

I get this image:

[image]

Edit 2-----------------------------------------------------------

```
structure(list(A5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), A9 = c(NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L), maf = c("9.33843e-01", "2.07735e-01", "9.28438e-01", 
"7.17963e-01", "1.02935e-01", "9.28281e-01")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** with new data:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -maf
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(name), as.numeric(maf), fill=factor(value))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
```

[image]

**First answer:**

Bring your data in long format then use `geom_boxplot()`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -maf
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, maf, fill=factor(value))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(A5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L), A9 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L
), maf = c(0.933843, 0.207735, 0.928438, 0.717963, 0.102935, 
0.928281, 0.9281, 0.28517, 0.267085, 0.928339, 0.0568334, 0.487848, 
0.222414, 0.337689, 0.109452, 0.0471361, 0.687674, 0.503323, 
0.893953, 0.913662)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Comment: Thanks that looks great, my actual data set is a little longer, and it kind of glitching out on the y axis, could it be the original data is still 9.33843e-01 for maf. Do you know how to convert between 9.33843e-01 and 0.933843?

Comment: I showed what im getting with the 9.33843e-01 value instead as an edit to the original post

Comment: Try `options(scipen=999)`

Comment: Would I do that on the column, how?

Comment: Or try this first: add `scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))` to ggplot e.g. at the end of ggplot `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))`

Comment: `options(scipen=999` is general for R. e.g. command line or script for all numbers.

Comment: So could I convert the column first than cbind it back?

Comment: When I add that code I get this:Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
 1: (function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print"))(x)
 2: print.ggplot(x)
 3: ggplot_build(x)
 4: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5: layout$train_position(data, scale_x(), scale_y())
 6: f(..., self = self)
 7: self$facet$train_scales(self$panel_scales_x, self$panel_scales_y, layout, data, self$facet_params)
 8: f(...)
 9: scale_apply(layer_data, y_vars, "train", SCALE_Y, y_scales)
10: lapply(vars, function(var)
Selection:

Comment: Please write `dput(head(df))` in the console, copy it and then add it to your question. However the code should be `df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -maf
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(name), maf, fill=factor(value))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))`

Comment: added output of dput(head(df)) above in new edit

Comment: Please see my update. The issue is that your `maf` column in your dataframe is not numeric. I guess it is `character`. Just add `is.numeric(maf)`. Tip: Before you start data manipulation use `str(df)` and have a look to data class of your columns. :-)